# 404 Page Not Found: /index

Tags: php, codeigniter

I asked my server support to clear `inodes` for me from my server and next my site is down, all I get is 404. these are my php logs  shown below:

> ERROR - 2019-09-24 23:22:04 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
>
> ERROR - 2019-09-24 23:22:04 --> 404 Page Not Found: Image/https:

Comment: Have you accessed the server to make sure those files exist? "clearing inodes" means "deleting files". So, they likely deleted the files.

Comment: my index and htaccess were somehow deleted I uploaded them from an older backup I had and then I started getting 404. Before that all I got was "failed to open stream: no such file or directory found"

Comment: asked my server support all they said was they didn't delete these files all they deleted was my "session/" files

Comment: Sorry for that, but I'm not sure what kind of help we can give you regarding this case. Do you have a specific question about that situation? You should consider contacting your server's support department, or restore your files from a backup.

Comment: thanks anyways :) just thought someone may know the solution

Comment: At least for the '/index' file. 1. make sure the file '/index' exists in the directory / of your server. If it does, 2. check that your server is configured to have its '/' directory correctly, so that its root directory '/' is the same, where the file is stored. 3. it can be a problem if you use something like mod_rewrite CORRECTION, no point 3 shouldn't be a problem. And it seems that those are not your php logs but logs of your server, which almost surely is a different program using another program 'php' to generate http responses (i.e. web pages).

Answer (score 0):

So, what happened was that the server guys ran some script that was probably written by thanos and it wiped out my application/core, application/helper and application/views. all these directories also have index files. So, when Codeigniter logs give you '404 Page Not Found: /index' it's not just your 'index' in '/' but maybe your index is missing in someother directory of the framework. Thanks for the help guys really appreciate it.